# How do I think about conditional probability in this situation?

Tags: conditional-probability, likelihood

I am trying to understand some data relating the likelihood of a positive stock return following a certain signal.  The frequency of positive returns differ across datasets (over a particular time period) some stocks have more positive returns than negative returns, while others have more negative returns than positive returns (but not by much). I want to understanding the likelihood of getting a positive return given the occurrence of what I have defined as a positive signal. Suppose positive vs negative signals occur randomly. This means (I think) that with periods or datasets when there were more positive than negative returns, the likelihood of of a positive signal being followed by a positive return would be greater than 50% - but this would actually be the result of having more positive returns.

How do I untangle the effect of having more favorable than unfavorable outcomes from measuring the reliability of the signal?

Is this a question about how to use Bayes' Theorem?

Comment: Some clarifications are needed regarding the structure of the data (for each stock separately): a) Do you look at signals of period $t$ in connection to returns in period $t+1$, or signals at period $t$ and returns also at period $t$ (because, say the sequential relation happens in the same time period given how you data is temporally grouped -e.g. you look at days and the signal happens at the beginning of the day, the return at the end of the day) b) In each period, does either a positive or a negative signal occurs, or both may occur? CONTD

Comment: CONTD c) Are there time periods when neither a positive nor a negative signal occurs? d) Does the same signal affects many stocks or each signal relates to a particular stock?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I am looking at conditions in a six month period and returns in the following month. I'm looking at a single potential signal which can take either positive or negative values and with a mean of about zero. Values close to zero must be considered to provide no information about the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining $R^+$ and $R^-$ the positive and negative returns, and $S^+$ and $S^-$ positive and negative signals (outside the "uninformative region" around zero that the OP mentions in the comments), then, indeed by Bayes's Theorem we have

$$P(R^+_{t+1} \mid S^+_t) = \frac {P(R^+_{t+1} , S^+_t)}{P(S^+_t)}$$

and in this approach it all boils down to determine the joint distribution of $\{R_{t+1} , S_t\}$ each seen as a dichotomous random variable taking two "values"(states) (positive / negative). To the degree that you can count the appearance in the data of the four possible pairs, $\{R_{t+1}^+ , S_t^+\}$, $\{R_{t+1}^+ , S_t^-\}$, $\{R_{t+1}^- , S_t^+\}$, $\{R_{t+1}^- , S_t^-\}$,

the $2 \times 2$ table of joint empirical relative frequencies that will emerge will, assuming the these r.v.'s are stationary, be an estimate of the joint distribution of $\{R_{t+1} , S_t\}$ (providing also marginal and conditional distributions), and will permit you to formally test whether the returns are indeed associated with the preceding signals.